# How do i start a storyboard/timeline in expression blend 4.0 when the page loads

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend

I am still a bit new to developing Silverlight applications in Microsoft Expression blend for web pages.

I have built a storyboard using Expression Blend 4.0. I would like for it to start in the browser when the page loads, automatically, but I have not been able to figure it out.

I have searched for answers on the web, but so far, the only answers I've found seem to be for earlier versions of Expression Blend, and the environments are too different for me to figure out how to apply them to Expression Blend 4.0.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, i found the answer to my own question.

1. On the left side select the "Assets" button (looks like double arrows).
2. Then go to "behaviors" in the dialog.
3. Select "ControlStroyboardAction."
4. On the right under the properties tab with the behavior selected, change event name to "loaded"
5. In the "Common Properties" within the properties tab, change "ControlStoryboardOption" to "play" and "StoryBoard" to the name of your animation.

Comment: Mark this as your own answer :-)  Just for the archives, this is one of those places where WPF and Silverlight differ. In WPF you could create a Trigger to fire the animation on Window Loaded (actually, when you create a new Storyboard, one will be created and added for you).  For Silverlight, Behaviors are the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Onload of the class you can call Storyboard.start();

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put this inside your code behind (.cs):

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
}

void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard sb = this.Resources["Name of Animation"] as Storyboard;
    sb.Begin();
}
```